# Selenium WebDriver is taking port 2 by default to start

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the below line to start Selenium WebDriver and not giving the port by default. It somehow points to port "2" on Linux machine most of the time.

```
java -jar C:/CTAT6/tools/selenium/2.53.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

Can we put any mechanism to set the port? 
What is the range to select the port for WebDriver?

Comment: Do you have the launch command when on Linux? The example given is for windows.

Comment: By mistake I pasted the windows command. I'm facing this launch issue on Linux

Comment: Please provide the command you are using to launch on Linux.

Comment: java -jar /localdisk/CTAT6/tools/selenium/2.53.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `-port` flag can be useful:

```
java -jar C:/CTAT6/tools/selenium/2.53.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub -port 4441
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#configuring-via-the-command-line-options).

Comment: I do not want to give port number. I hope it will take any available port by default